# Problem with generating array with data from Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a problem with getting data into array from Google Spreadsheet. I have a custom range set up, but instead of getting data, while logging the array I get an empty array.

Code there the issue is:

```
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ssid");
  const s = ss.getSheetByName("Events");
  const srange = s.getRange(2, 1, s.getLastRow(), 8);
  //var rangeArray = s.getDataRange().getValues();
  var rangeArray = srange.getValues().slice(-2)[0];
  Logger.log("rangeArray value: ", rangeArray);
```

I expect to get a full array in rangeArray to work on it and create documents, but rangeArray variable is empty. Where is an error?

Answer (score 0):

To use Logger.log the way you have shown you need to include the c style formatting characters such as "rangeArray value : %d".  Since there is none nothing is printed.

Replace

```
Logger.log("rangeArray value: ", rangeArray);
```

With

```
Logger.log("rangeArray value: "+rangeArray);
```